# splitting a vector with strings

Tags: r, string, split

I have a vector, which is filled with strings of length 2:

```
vec <-c( "00", "10", "00", "01", "11", "11", "10", "00",...)
```

I want now to split the strings of the vector into the length 1:

```
result <- "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0",...)
```

The last step is to merge the vector entries to strings of length 8:

```
qpsk <- "00100001", "11111000",...)
```

I know there is the function strsplit and the function paste, but i don't know how to use it in this case. 
Is there a efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you merge or paste `vec` by 4 elements to create the string of length 8 ?

Comment: @MamounBenghezal because it is the task to split the string and then to merge them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
strsplit(paste(vec, collapse=''), '(?<=.{8})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "00100001" "11111000" "0100"
```

#### data

```
 vec <-c( "00", "10", "00", "01", "11", "11", "10", "00", "01", "00")
```